# Prevent onClick event to happen in all rows instead of one sigle row per click

Tags: reactjs, typescript, events, render, material-table

I have  a table in which a  I have a button that appears in every single row. This button displays an  `onClick event` which adds two buttons elements below.

**What happens** :  when I click on a button  the `onClick event`  is done in every single row instead of just the only one I clicked.

**What I expect to happen**: when clicking to the button in *one* row the event it's done on that single row.

`Note` : I am using material table and in one the of the columns I have a `render method`  and the structure of  the button is like the following:

```
<Button
              disableRipple
              className={(classes.buttonState, classes.textButtonStatePending)}
              onMouseEnter={handleHover} //makes the buttons appear
              onMouseLeave={handleHoverAway} //makes the buttons dissapear
              onClick={handleHover}
              onChange={handleHover}
            >
              Pending
            </Button>
```

This is my event that makes hover over the button and it must show my components:

```
const handleHover = (): void => {
    setShowButtonGroup(true);
  };
```

Comment: can you put `event.stopPropagation();` in your `handleHover` function

Comment: You'll need to use a unique identifier such as an `id` for each row so that you can pass it to your `onClick` handler and know which row has been clicked

Comment: @AmruthLS Is it a method imported from REact ? Look my funciton :                                               const handleHover = (): void => {
    setShowButtonGroup(true);
    stopPropagation();
  };

Comment: no need `handleHover(event){ event.stopPropagation(); }` your function should look like this

Comment: @WillJenkins you might be right.. can you give me an example about how to do it  in code ?

Comment: @Karol add some more code - show where you're rendering your rows and what `handleHover` currently does

Comment: @WillJenkins I am using this library https://material-table.com/#/ but I cannot find where does it says how to add a key or id to a row. Can you  give me a hand ?

Comment: I don't know how to pass the key to the button either :                                          
        onClick={  handleHover(time.teamMember[1])}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So looking at the docs, it looks like a custom render method for a table column looks like this:

```
render: rowData => <YourCustomComponent />
```

In your case, you are rendering a `<Button>` with a bunch of handlers, including `onClick`. Assuming your `rowData` has some kind of unique value like `id`, you can use this to tie the button click to the row:

```
render: rowData => <Button onClick={() => handleClick(row.id)}>Pending</Button>
```

I've added a separate click handler for this, it's not necessary but it helps to keep things separate. So now you need a click handler that is 'row aware' - normally this might look something like this:

```
const handleClick = (id): void => {
    setVisibleRowId(id)
 };
```

Finally, you use this `id` wherever you are rendering the buttons that you want to show/hide, so if it's in another column render method:

```
render: rowData => rowData.id === visibleRowId ? <Button>My row was clicked</Button> : undefined
```

ETA: regarding your additional question

> I don't know how to pass the key to the button either : `onClick={ handleHover(time.teamMember[1])}`

This will call your `handleHover` function on every render, which you don't want. You have wrap this call in a new function - i.e. pass a function that is invoked only on click:

```
onClick={() => handleHover(time.teamMember[1])}
```

Comment: Thanks I already tried it like this :                       onClick={() => handleClickHover(rowData.id)}